# How to migrate String Datatype column to BigDecimal Datatype column in Talend

Tags: database-migration, talend

I have old DB in which ID's are stored as STRING datatype. I want these data to be migrated to my new DB in which IDs as BIGDECIMAL datatype. Someone please suggest how to do that in TALEND migration tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using tMap expression builder, see the image for more details.

[image]

use expression like below with null handling.

```
row1.id!=null?new BigDecimal(row1.id):new BigDecimal(0)
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to filter out null ids in a previous step rather than set them to 0 in your ternary because they shouldn't exist (but if they do you don't want a null pointer exception) and if they do then you'll want to dig into them manually and certainly not just default them to 0 which could lead to failed inserts due to unique constraints (which would not be a concern if the value is null at least in MySQL as unique constraints allow for multiple nulls).

Comment: Please consider using tConvertType. That component allows data type conversions.